# Is there an IIS Express equivalent for IIS application pool Shutdown Time Limit (seconds) setting?

Tags: asp.net-core, build, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I am coding an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application in Visual Studio 2017. Sometimes, the build cannot end due to binaries being used by IIS Express. This solves automatically after retrying the build (it typically requires 10-15 seconds).

I have also tried an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application in Visual Studio 2017 directly bound in IIS. The issue also happens there from time to time, but I was able to mitigate it by greatly reducing `Shutdown Time Limit (seconds)`:

[image: IIS Application Pool Shutdown Time Limit setting]

I am trying to do the same in IIS Express, but cannot find a similar setting. I have looked in both global (in my user) and local configuration file (.vs\config\applicationhost.config), but cannot find anything similar.

**Question:** Is there an IIS Express equivalent for IIS application pool Shutdown Time Limit (seconds) setting?

Comment: IIS Express does not have application pool at all, so no such setting.

Comment: @LexLi - ok, but it has to have some kind of workers that handle the requests or something similar. I expect that Visual Studio notifies it to stop in order to be able to overwrite the binaries.

Comment: There is almost zero documentation on that part, so you should get used to it or report that as bugs to Microsoft.

Comment: @LexLi - well, I can live with this although it is kind of annoying. I would say that this kind of situations is where IIS is better choice than IIS Express. Thanks.